# Batch processing using IObservable

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, system.reactive

My server side sends me batches of messages. The number of messages in a batch and frequency is arbitrary. At times, I get messages at 1 minute intervals and sometimes no messages for an hour. Anywhere from 1 to 10 messages.

My current implementation uses `Observable.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))` to group and send the messages to subscriber.

Instead of having to check every 5 seconds, is there a way to configure the Observable to say send your buffered messages to subscriber if there's an x seconds delay between two messages.

How to avoid an unnecessary timer ticking every 5 seconds? (I'm open to other suggestions to optimize the batch processing.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Using a bufferClosingSelector factory method

decPL suggested using the overload of `Buffer` that accepts a `bufferClosingSelector` - a factory function that is called at the opening of a new buffer. It produces a stream whose first `OnNext()` or `OnCompleted()` signals flushing the current buffer. decPLs code looked like this:

```
observable.Buffer(() => observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
```

This makes considerable progress towards a solution, but it has a couple of problems:

- The server will not send messages during periods of activity where messages are published consistently within the throttle duration. This could result in large, infrequently published lists.
- There are multiple subscriptions to the source; if it is cold this may have unintended side effects. The `bufferClosingSelector` factory is called after *each* buffer closing, so if the source is cold it would be throttling from the initial events, rather than the most recent.

#### Preventing indefinite throttling

We need to use an additional mechanism to limit the buffer length and prevent indefinite throttling. `Buffer` has an overload that allows you to specify a maximum length, but unfortunately you can't combine this with a closing selector.

Let's call the desired buffer length limit ***n***. Recall the first `OnNext` of the closing selector is enough to close the buffer, so all we need to do is `Merge` the throttle with a counting stream that sends `OnNext` after ***n*** events from the source. We can use `.Take(n).LastAsync()` to do this; take the first ***n*** events but ignore all but the last of this. This is a very useful pattern in Rx.

#### Making the source "hot"

In order to address the issue of the `bufferClosingSelector` factory resubscribing to the source, we need to use the common pattern of `.Publish().RefCount()` on the source to give us a stream that will only send the most recent events to subscribers. This is also a very useful pattern to remember.

#### Solution

Here is the reworked code, where the throttle duration is merged with a counter:

```
var throttleDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
var bufferSize = 3;

// single subscription to source
var sourcePub = source.Publish().RefCount();

var output = sourcePub.Buffer(
    () => sourcePub.Throttle(throttleDuration) 
                   .Merge(sourcePub.Take(bufferSize).LastAsync()));
```

#### Production Ready Code & Tests

Here is a production ready implementation with tests (use nuget packages rx-testing & nunit). Note the parameterization of the scheduler to support testing.

```
public static partial class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> BufferNearEvents<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        TimeSpan maxInterval,
        int maxBufferSize,
        IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        if (scheduler == null) scheduler = ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance;
        if (maxBufferSize <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                "maxBufferSize", "maxBufferSize must be positive");

        var publishedSource = source.Publish().RefCount();

        return publishedSource.Buffer(
            () => publishedSource
                .Throttle(maxInterval, scheduler)
                .Merge(publishedSource.Take(maxBufferSize).LastAsync()));
    }
}

public class BufferNearEventsTests : ReactiveTest
{
    [Test]
    public void CloseEventsAreBuffered()
    {
        TimeSpan maxInterval = TimeSpan.FromTicks(200);
        const int maxBufferSize = 1000;

        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var source = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
            OnNext(100, 1),
            OnNext(200, 2),
            OnNext(300, 3));

        IList<int> expectedBuffer = new [] {1, 2, 3};
        var expectedTime = maxInterval.Ticks + 300;

        var results = scheduler.CreateObserver<IList<int>>();

        source.BufferNearEvents(maxInterval, maxBufferSize, scheduler)
              .Subscribe(results);

        scheduler.AdvanceTo(1000);

        results.Messages.AssertEqual(
            OnNext<IList<int>>(expectedTime, buffer => CheckBuffer(expectedBuffer, buffer)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void FarEventsAreUnbuffered()
    {
        TimeSpan maxInterval = TimeSpan.FromTicks(200);
        const int maxBufferSize = 1000;

        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var source = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
            OnNext(1000, 1),
            OnNext(2000, 2),
            OnNext(3000, 3));

        IList<int>[] expectedBuffers =
        {
            new[] {1},
            new[] {2},
            new[] {3}
        };

        var expectedTimes = new[]
        {
            maxInterval.Ticks + 1000,
            maxInterval.Ticks + 2000,
            maxInterval.Ticks + 3000
        };  

        var results = scheduler.CreateObserver<IList<int>>();

        source.BufferNearEvents(maxInterval, maxBufferSize, scheduler)
              .Subscribe(results);

        scheduler.AdvanceTo(10000);

        results.Messages.AssertEqual(
            OnNext<IList<int>>(expectedTimes[0], buffer => CheckBuffer(expectedBuffers[0], buffer)),
            OnNext<IList<int>>(expectedTimes[1], buffer => CheckBuffer(expectedBuffers[1], buffer)),
            OnNext<IList<int>>(expectedTimes[2], buffer => CheckBuffer(expectedBuffers[2], buffer)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void UpToMaxEventsAreBuffered()
    {
        TimeSpan maxInterval = TimeSpan.FromTicks(200);
        const int maxBufferSize = 2;

        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var source = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
            OnNext(100, 1),
            OnNext(200, 2),
            OnNext(300, 3));

        IList<int>[] expectedBuffers =
        {
            new[] {1,2},
            new[] {3}
        };

        var expectedTimes = new[]
        {
            200, /* Buffer cap reached */
            maxInterval.Ticks + 300
        };

        var results = scheduler.CreateObserver<IList<int>>();

        source.BufferNearEvents(maxInterval, maxBufferSize, scheduler)
              .Subscribe(results);

        scheduler.AdvanceTo(10000);

        results.Messages.AssertEqual(
            OnNext<IList<int>>(expectedTimes[0], buffer => CheckBuffer(expectedBuffers[0], buffer)),
            OnNext<IList<int>>(expectedTimes[1], buffer => CheckBuffer(expectedBuffers[1], buffer)));
    }

    private static bool CheckBuffer<T>(IEnumerable<T> expected, IEnumerable<T> actual)
    {
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Learned a lot myself today, especially as I had to dig into decompiled code to realize why a single `Observable.Take` allows this to work iteratively. Thanks!

Comment: I also improved the explanation to cover that point more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your description correctly, `Observable.Buffer` is still your friend, just using the overload that causes an observable event to dictate when buffered items should be sent. Something as follows:

```
observable.Buffer(() => observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
```

Comment: +1 Nice, I extended this idea a bit to deal with a couple of minor issues. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it seems related to [my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858974/rx-group-batch-bursts-of-elements-in-an-observable-sequence). Enigmativity found a nice way to do what I think you want to achieve so I thought I'd share. I wrapped the solution in an extension method:

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T[]> Batch<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, TimeSpan timespan)
    {
        return observable.GroupByUntil(x => 1, g => Observable.Timer(timespan))
                         .Select(x => x.ToArray())
                         .Switch();
    }
}
```

And it could be used like this:

```
observableSource.Batch(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```