# Grouping IObservable by both property and timeout

Tags: c#, .net, observable, system.reactive

I need to transform an stream of objects to a stream of batches of objects, grouping them by a property value using **Reactive Extensions**:

```
class Record
{
    public string Group;
    public int Value;
}

IObservable<List<Record>> Process(IObservable<Record> source, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    // ...
}
```

A batch is finished and sent to the output stream when either of these happens:

- A new object comes from source stream and its `Group` value differs from the previous value
- There have been no new objects in the source stream for `N` seconds

For example, if `a1` means `new Record { Group = "a", Value = 1}`:

```
input:   -a1-a2-a3-b1-b2-
output:  -[a1, a2, a3]-[b1, b2]-

input:   -a1-a2----------a3-
output:  -[a1, a2]-------[a3]-
```

Tried various combinations of `GroupByUntil`, `Debounce`, `Buffer`, and `Timer` to no avail. How is it done?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858974/rx-group-batch-bursts-of-elements-in-an-observable-sequence/29859685#29859685) can be helpful for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick was to use `GroupByUntil` with `Throttle` on itself:

```
IObservable<List<Record>> Process(IObservable<Record> source, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    return source.GroupByUntil(x => x.Group, g => g.Throttle(timeout))
                 .SelectMany(x => x.ToList());
}
```